# Comparing Network Traffic to Authorized List(s) via Domain Name

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse through network traffic and compare the domain names in the traffic to a list of the most common websites. the intent is to print all the site names that are not on the list of common websites

```
with open('/Users/downloads/scripting_for_security/resources/top_100.txt') as f:
    safeAdd = f.readlines(),


with open('/Users/downloads/scripting_for_security/resources/traffic_log.txt') as n:
    netTraffic = n.readlines(),

domainTraffic = re.findall(r'\s(?:www.)?(\w+.com)', netTraffic)


for i in safeAdd:
    for e in domainTraffic:
        if i != e:
            print(e)
```

getting a type error

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         8     netTraffic = n.readlines(),
>         9 
>   ---> 10 domainTraffic = re.findall(r'\s(?:www.)?(\w+.com)', netTraffic)
>        11 
>        12
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py in findall(pattern, string, flags)
>       221 
>       222     Empty matches are included in the result."""
>   --> 223     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
>       224 
>       225 def finditer(pattern, string, flags=0):
>
> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

netTraffic is a list as per https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

findall expects a second argument of type string https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously, [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.findall) expects a string and you are passing a list. One of the ways to tackle this could be to iterate over the list of strings  (`netTraffic`) and build a list of all matches found (`domainTraffic`). I've shown this below:

```py
with open('/Users/downloads/scripting_for_security/resources/top_100.txt') as f:
    safeAdd = f.readlines(),


with open('/Users/downloads/scripting_for_security/resources/traffic_log.txt') as n:
    netTraffic = n.readlines(),

#initialize empty list
domainTraffic = []

#iterate over each value and add matches to the list
for net in netTraffic:
    domainTraffic.extend(re.findall(r'\s(?:www.)?(\w+.com)', str(net))

#Use list comprehension to filter out the safeAdds
filtered_list = [add for add in domainTraffic if add not in safeAdd]

print(filtered_list)
```

You could also [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the list into a long string and then run `re.findall` on the combined string. It really depends on what your strings are.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are  passing a `list` of `lines` not a text to `re.findall`,
use `read()` instead of `readlines()`:

```py
with open('data.txt') as f:
    print(type(f.readlines()))  # list
    print(type(f.read()))       # str accepted by the re.findall or any other function
```

In your code change this:

```
safeAdd = f.read()

netTraffic = n.read()
```

and remove the `,` , `netTraffic`  will be a `tuple` contains one `list` of `lines`, check this out:

```
  x = 1, # equavalent to x = (1,)  result is tuple
  x = 1 # is equavalent to x = (1) without "," it's integer
```